# How to make a Delete operator with its confirmation window?

Tags: python, add-on

I would like to have a Delete button that can Delete Global using Shift-Click.
It deletes globally fine, but I'm not getting the confirmation window even if I set `confirm=True`
Could you help me find what I'm doing wrong?

````
class MYADDON_OT_Delete(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.delete"
    bl_label = "Delete Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    obj: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    use_global: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = bpy.data.objects[self.obj]
        obj.select_set(True)
        if self.use_global:
            bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True, confirm=True)
        else:
            bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=True)
        return{'FINISHED'}
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if event.shift == True:
            self.use_global = True
        else:
            self.use_global = False
        return self.execute(context)
```
````

Comment: Try `bpy.ops.object.delete('INVOKE_DEFAULT', confirm=True)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Invoke the `WindowManager.invoke_confirm`**

IMO the way this was is confusing. If your desire is to delete an object by name, can instead get it from the scene by name and remove it.

As it was would remove active, selected and "obj" if it existed, or simply throw an error if it didn't.

Have passed an override to the delete object operator to only delete the object known with name `self.obj` if it is linked to the context scene.

Test script, run in text editor throws up the confirm menu.

```
import bpy

class MYADDON_OT_Delete(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "myaddon.delete"
    bl_label = "Delete Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    obj: bpy.props.StringProperty()
    use_global: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

    @classmethod
    def description(self, context, event):
        return f"Delete {event.obj}"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = scene.objects.get(self.obj)
        if obj:
            return bpy.ops.object.delete(
                {
                     "object" : None,
                     "selected_objects" : [obj]
                 },
                 use_global = self.use_global
            )

        return {'CANCELLED'}
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.use_global = event.shift
        wm = context.window_manager
        if event.shift:
            return wm.invoke_confirm(self, event)
        return self.execute(context)

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout        
    op = layout.operator("myaddon.delete")
    op.obj = "Cube"

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    bpy.utils.register_class(MYADDON_OT_Delete)
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.prepend(draw)
    bpy.ops.myaddon.delete('INVOKE_DEFAULT', obj="Cube")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I learn a lot from all your answers on Stack Exchange.
I agree my example code was confusing and lazy, your answer is much cleaner.

Comment: Thankyou, the feedback is appreciated.  Appreciate any python  question that shows effort and code.   _So many do not, ..._  Btw if you look at revision intially answered using API methods. Re `use_global` This was simpler pre 2.8 as could either unlink from scene objects (False)  or delete from blend.  Could make a good question as in as much as could code it, a quick attempt  seems overly complicated to find the collection that is linked to scene to unlink object from.  Also noticed that answer was accepted since removed... any specific reason?.

Comment: Your example will also open the confirmation window when not holding shift, I want to only ask for confirmation when deleting globally. The other reason is that I want to use this operator with a button, so it doesn't show how to use 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' for the button.
I am looking into fixing these two and will add it as an answer, but your answer is still extremely valuable :)

Comment: `INVOKE_DEFAULT` is the default for a button.

Comment: Ah ok, I was confused by this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51135822/blender-python-add-operator-to-menu-with-invoke-default

So in my case I just changed the invoke with a condition `if self.use_global` to use either `wm.invoke_confirm(self,event)` or `self.execute(context)`